# Correct use of Object Initializer

Tags: c#-4.0, initialization

I have a variant for initializing DbRecordData

```
public class DbRecordData : IList<DbFieldValue>, ICollection<DbFieldValue>, IEnumerable<DbFieldValue>, IEnumerable
{
    public DbRecordData(DataRow row);
    public DbRecordData(int countValues);

    public int Count { get; }

    public DbFieldValue this[int index] { get; set; }

    public int Add(DbFieldValue item);
    public int Add(string fieldName, object value);
    public int Add(DataRow row, string fieldName, SqlDbType dataType);
    public int Add(string fieldName, SqlDbType dataType, object value);
    public void Clear();
    public void FillSqlParameters(SqlParameter[] parameters, int fromIndex);
}
```

This is initializing:

```
 DbRecordData dbRecord = new DbRecordData(2)
                        {
                            {"VehMarkName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, vehMarkName},
                            {"refVehTypeId", SqlDbType.Int, refVehTypeId}
                        };
```

This works and does not create warnings, but i haven't found same examples in msdn.
is this variant correct? or is it hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly works, yes. It's the equivalent of:

```
DbRecordData tmp = new DbRecordData(2);
tmp.Add("VehMarkName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, vehMarkName);
tmp.Add("refVehTypeId", SqlDbType.Int, refVehTypeId);
DbRecordData dbRecord = tmp;
```

If that's basically the code you'd have written otherwise, then I'd prefer your object initializer version. If you want *different* code to that, then you may want to rethink things.

Comment: Is the @DmitryRazumikhin code with the new keyword equivalent to my without it? Is it documented feature?

Comment: @user1482814: From a language perspective, it's absolutely documented and supported. As for whether `DbRecordData.Add(string, SqlDbType, object)` works the same as `DbRecordData.Add(DbFieldValue)` - that's a different matter, and one for you to look into.

Answer (score -1):

It works, but not documented in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

**Using undocumented features is not correct for enterprise code. Because support of this construction could be broken in latest versions of .NET**

Documented way is

```
DbRecordData dbRecord = new DbRecordData(2)
                        {
                            new DbFieldValue("VehMarkName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, vehMarkName),
                            new DbFieldValue("refVehTypeId", SqlDbType.Int, refVehTypeId)
                        };
```

but this version more complex than just

```
DbRecordData dbRecord = new DbRecordData(2)
dbRecord.Add("VehMarkName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, vehMarkName);
dbRecord.Add("refVehTypeId", SqlDbType.Int, refVehTypeId);
```

Comment: It *is* supported in C#. Just look at [that MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx), which says "To initialize a dictionary *or any collection whose **Add** method takes multiple parameters*"

Comment: In this example used 'new' operator. Code above does not have a 'new' - this other syntax.

Comment: It's *absolutely* documented. Look at the collection initializer syntax in the language specification - there's nothing hokey/undocumented about this at all.

Comment: (It' section 7.6.10.3 of the C# spec, if you wanted to look it up.)

Comment: Yes, I found this. Thank you for clarifying!